# Program that uses functions to work with linked lists is working but produces results that are 1 off

Tags: c, list, function

I am writing a program for class that uses functions to work with linked lists. My program is working except for it is producing results that are 1 off. 
The functions are as described below -

- `printRev` -
  This function will print the list in reverse, making use of the doubly
  linked functionality of the list.
- `removeNode` -
  This function will remove a node from the list where 
  data matches the input value. For simplicity, you can just remove the first occurrence of a value
- `insertFront` -
  Inserts a new node to the front of the list
- `insertBack` -
  Inserts a new node to the back of the list
- `Print` - 
  Prints the current linked list
- `Max` - 
  Returns the maximum value in the list. (does not print)
- `Min` -
  Returns the minimum value in the list (does not print)
- `locInList` -
  Returns the location of a 
  number in the list. (does not print)

My `print`, `printRev`, `Min` and `locInList` functions appear to be working properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
        int data;
        struct node *next;
        struct node *prev;
};
typedef struct node node;


void printRev(node* head);
node* removeNode(node* head, int d);
node* insertFront(node* head, int d);
node* insertBack(node* head, int d);
void print(node* head);
int max(node* head);
int min(node* head);
int locInList(node* head, int x);

int main()
{

        node* head = NULL;

        head = insertFront(head, 5);
        head = insertFront(head, 4);
        head = insertBack(head, 6);
        head = insertBack(head, 7);
        print(head);
        printRev(head);

        printf("Max: %d\n", max(head));
        printf("Min: %d\n", min(head));
        printf("locInList 5: %d\n", locInList(head, 5));
        printf("locInList 9: %d\n", locInList(head, 9));

        head = removeNode(head, 6);
        print(head);
        head = removeNode(head, 4);
        print(head);
        head = removeNode(head, 7);
        print(head);


        return 0;
}

void printRev(node* head)
{
        node *cur = head;
        node *tmp = NULL;
        if (cur == NULL){
                return;
        }else{
                while(cur->next != NULL){
                       cur = cur->next;
                                        }
                while(cur != NULL){
                        printf("%d ", cur->data);
                        cur = cur->prev; 
                                } 
        }
                printf("\n");
}

node* removeNode(node* head, int d)
{

        node *tmp = head->next;
        head->data = head->next->data;
        head->next = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
        return head;
}

node* insertFront(node* head, int d)
{
        node *tmp = NULL;
        tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
        tmp->data = d;
        tmp->prev = NULL;

        if(head == NULL){
                return tmp;
                        }

        head->prev = tmp;
        tmp->next = head;
        return tmp;
}

node* insertBack(node* head, int d)
{
        node *tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));
 tmp->data = d;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        if(head == NULL){
                tmp->prev = NULL;
                return tmp;
        }
        else{
        node *end = head;

        while(end->next != NULL){
                end = end->next;
        }
                end->next = tmp;
                tmp->prev = end;
            }

        return head;
}

void print(node* head)
{

        node *tmp = head;

        while(tmp != NULL){
                printf("%d ", tmp->data);
                tmp = tmp->next;
                        }
        printf("\n");
}

int max (node* head)
{

        int max = head->data;
        node *tmp = NULL;
        tmp = head;
 while(tmp->next != NULL){
                if(tmp->data >= max){
                        max = tmp->data;
                }
                        tmp = tmp->next;
                }
        return max;
}

int min (node* head)
{
        int min = head->data;
        node *tmp = NULL;
        tmp = head;

        while(tmp->next != NULL){
                if(tmp->data <= min){
                        min = tmp->data;
  }
                        tmp = tmp->next;
                        }
        return min;
}
int locInList(node* head, int x)
{

        int i = 0;
        node *tmp = NULL;
        tmp = head;

        while(tmp != NULL){
                if(tmp->data == x){
                return i;
                }else{
                i++;
                tmp = tmp->next;
                        }  }
                return -1;

}
```

I expect output of -

4 5 6 7
7 6 5 4
Max: 7
Min: 4
locInList 5: 1
locInList 9: -1
4 5 7
5 7
5

The output I am getting is -
4 5 6 7
7 6 5 4
Max: 6
Min: 4
locInList 5: 1
locInList 9: -1
5 6 7
6 7
7

Answer (score 1):

You should change `while(tmp->next != NULL)` to `while(tmp != NULL)`. As it is now you are not checking the current element if there is no next element.